# How to Generate a Link to download a File in asp.net MVC if domain name is unknown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I have small Asp MVC 3 project where I need to create link to file, but I don’t know what the name of the site will be.
So in my ActionResult I need to have next

```
public ActionResult LinkToFile()
         {

var fields = new[]{
                        new { type = "string",  name = "name" ,  title = "Name"} ,
                        new { type = "string" ,  name = "link" ,  title = "Link" }
                    };

                 var meta = new { fields };
                 var data = new[]
                           {
                               new
                                   {
                                       name = "PDF file",
                                        link =  http://example.com/files/file.pdf

                                   }
                           };


                 var res = new { contentType = "LinkToFile", id = 1, meta, data };
                 return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

   }
```

As I said before, I don’t know what the name of the site will be, where I can this: http://example.com ? 
The file is located on the server in folder name “file”

Comment: Why not just use a relative URL like `/files/file.pdf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/53/how-do-i-get-paths-and-url-fragments-from-the-httprequest-object

There's the whole list i gues :)

Answer (score 2):

infoexpert.it,

not 100% clear here, but perhaps you could use:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

or:

```
Request.UrlReferrer.Host // or Request.Url.Host
```

etc..

and extrapolate the info you needed??

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var url = Request.Url;
```

To get the url of the site.
If this is to much you can always trim off some access url

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri(Request.Url.Host);
Uri uri = new Uri(baseUri, "files/file.pdf");
```